# sqlite ingores index

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

I have a table, with columns A,B,C,D

There exists and index on [A],[B]

I have a query such as
`SELECT A,B,C,D, From MyTable WHERE A=? AND B=? ORDER BY C DESC`

I would exepct the DB engine to use the index, narrow results where `A` and `B` match. And then - sort the results w.r.t. `C` if necessary.

The query executed surprisingly slow. Analyzing it (by `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`) revealed that the DB engine only uses partial search by `A`, then - scan.

If I remove the `ORDER BY` part, then the whole index is used.

Is this the expected behavior? Can I make a hint for sqlite engine to use the whole index?

Comment: It can't effectively use the index because of the order.  If you index A, B, *and* C, the index should be applicable.

Comment: @erik258: I understand this, if I add `C` to the index - it will be used.
But technically it should be able to use the index to narrow its search. I don't understand why the engine decides to use only `A` from the index, this makes no sense IMHO.

Comment: You can use `ANALYZE` to generate statistics on the table(s) that the query planner can use to decide on the index to use. Might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the column `c` is not indexed, the database must retrieve all rows that meet the conditions specified for columns `a` and `b`, and then sort them. When using indexes, the database needs to read complete rows from the disk based on the matched index entries. These rows are stored in different locations on the disk, requiring random I/O. On the other hand, full table scans use sequential I/O, which is much faster than random I/O. Therefore, when loading more than 10%-30% of the rows in a table at once, most databases will opt for a full table scan. This threshold is not fixed and depends on various factors.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.
In my specific case this was an awful decision, because the `ORDER BY` in practice was never involved, most results were either empty or had 1 row.
But looks like this is due to ineffective heuristics by sqlite. I understand now the rationale behind the selection of sequential scan.